# Visual Studio Online TortoiseGIT integration

Tags: azure-devops, tortoisegit

Is it possible to integrate Visual Studio Online with a TortoiseGIT issue tracker? It would be nice to type # and see a list of workitems to commit against.

Currently I can commit by starting a message with #[workitem number] and it will tie up in Visual Studio Online. E.g. #1 commit message

I can't seem to find any issue trackers when looking from a repository;

[image: Trying to add a Visual Studio Online issue tracker]

Comment: How about https://github.com/13xforever/turtletfs?

Comment: @starain-MSFT that project targets Team Foundation Server, not Visual Studio Online. I've looked through the code, and it looks like a good starting place to roll my own provider.

Comment: I don't find the provider for VSTS, but you can build a provide by yourself with TFS/VSTS API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [turtletfs](https://github.com/13xforever/turtletfs) provider (Contains source code) uses TFS/VSTS API to get work items from TFS/VSTS, but this provider is too old, you can build the provider by yourself with TFS/VSTS API.

The simple code of get work items with TFS/VSTS API:

```
var tfs = TeamFoundationServerFactory.GetServer("https://[account].visualstudio.com");
            tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
            var workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)tfs.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
          var r=  workItemStore.Query("select[System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State], [System.Tags] from WorkItems where [System.TeamProject] = 'ScrumStarain' and [System.WorkItemType] = 'Product Backlog Item' and [System.State] <> ''");
```

Another sample:

```
var u = new Uri("https://[account].visualstudio.com");
VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential(new NetworkCredential("[alternate user name]", "[password]")));
 var connection = new VssConnection(u, c);

            var workitemClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
var result = workitemClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models.Wiql() { Query = "select[System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State], [System.Tags] from WorkItems where [System.TeamProject] = 'ScrumStarain2' and [System.WorkItemType] = 'Product Backlog Item' and [System.State] <> ''" }, "ScrumStarain2").Result;
```